# String to DateTime format

Tags: datetime

I need to convert the string getting from JSON (For eg: 2014-08-26T17:50:20.000-0700) to this format '6/9/2014 11:57' to store in field which is of text format in salesforce.

Also per my requirement the field which i store date should not be in date/time format.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
Date dt = Date.valueOf('2014-08-26T17:50:20.000-0700');

String dts = DateTime.newInstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day()).format('d-MM-YYYY');

System.debug(logginglevel.error, dts);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about to use something like this that also handle the timezone (in case daylight saving changes too )

```
Datetime GMTDate = Datetime.newInstance(myDate.year(),myDate.year().month(), myDate.year().day(),0,0,0);
String strConvertedDate = GMTDate.format('MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm','America/Mexico_City');
```

Comment: Note you should use `M/d` instead of `MM/dd` because the OP requested `6/9`, not `06/09`.